# Spring Webflux Websocket Security - Basic Authentication

Tags: spring-security, websocket, spring-webflux

PROBLEM: I am not getting Spring Security with Websockets to work in a Webflux project.

NOTE: I am using Kotlin instead of Java.

DEPENDENCIES:

- Spring Boot 2.0.0
- Spring Security 5.0.3
- Spring WebFlux 5.0.4

**IMPORTANT UPDATE:** I have raised a Spring Issue bug (March 30) [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12701) and one of the Spring security maintainers said its NOT SUPPORTED but they can add it for [Spring Security 5.1.0 M2](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/milestone/106).

**LINK:** [Add WebFlux WebSocket Support #5188](http://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/5188)

**Webflux Security Configuration**

```
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
class SecurityConfig
{
    @Bean
    fun configure(http: ServerHttpSecurity): SecurityWebFilterChain
    {

        return http.authorizeExchange()
            .pathMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .anyExchange().authenticated()
            .and().httpBasic()
            .and().formLogin().disable().csrf().disable()
            .build()
    }

    @Bean
    fun userDetailsService(): MapReactiveUserDetailsService
    {
        val user = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
            .username("user")
            .password("pass")
            .roles("USER")
            .build()

        return MapReactiveUserDetailsService(user)
    }
}
```

**Webflux Websocket Configuration**

```
@Configuration
class ReactiveWebSocketConfiguration
{
    @Bean
    fun webSocketMapping(handler: WebSocketHandler): HandlerMapping
    {
        val map = mapOf(Pair("/event", handler))
        val mapping = SimpleUrlHandlerMapping()
        mapping.order = -1
        mapping.urlMap = map
        return mapping
    }

    @Bean
    fun handlerAdapter() = WebSocketHandlerAdapter()

    @Bean
    fun websocketHandler() = WebSocketHandler { session ->

        // Should print authenticated principal BUT does show NULL
        println("${session.handshakeInfo.principal.block()}")

        // Just for testing we send hello world to the client
        session.send(Mono.just(session.textMessage("hello world")))
    }
}
```

**Client Code**

```
// Lets create a websocket and pass Basic Auth to it
new WebSocket("ws://user:pass@localhost:8000/event");
// ...
```

**Obserservations**

1. In the websocket handler the principal shows **null**
2. The client can connect without being authenticated. If I do `WebSocket("ws://localhost:8000/event")` without the Basic Auth it stills works! So Spring Security does not authenticate anything.

What I am missing?
What I do wrong?

Comment: I have exactly the same question. Is there any help??

Comment: We have to wait until the Spring Security Team has implemented that feature (Basic Auth over Websockets). However, if you cant wait you have to change your authentication mechanism.

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/5188

Comment: Plus the issue or add comments to let Rob Winch know that this issue is important :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could advise you to implement your `own authentication mechanism` instead of exploiting Spring Security.

When `WebSocket` connection is about to establish it uses `handshake` mechanism accompanied by an `UPGRADE` request. Base on that, our idea would be to use our own handler for the request and perform authentication there.

Fortunately, Spring Boot has [`RequestUpgradeStrategy`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/socket/server/RequestUpgradeStrategy.html) for such purpose. On top of that, based on the application server what you use, Spring provides a default implementation of those strategies. As I use `Netty` bellow the class would be [ReactorNettyRequestUpgradeStrategy](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/socket/server/upgrade/ReactorNettyRequestUpgradeStrategy.html).

Here is the suggested prototype:

```java
/**
 * Based on {@link ReactorNettyRequestUpgradeStrategy}
 */
@Slf4j
@Component
public class BasicAuthRequestUpgradeStrategy implements RequestUpgradeStrategy {

    private int maxFramePayloadLength = NettyWebSocketSessionSupport.DEFAULT_FRAME_MAX_SIZE;

    private final AuthenticationService service;

    public BasicAuthRequestUpgradeStrategy(AuthenticationService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> upgrade(ServerWebExchange exchange, //
                              WebSocketHandler handler, //
                              @Nullable String subProtocol, //
                              Supplier<HandshakeInfo> handshakeInfoFactory) {

        ServerHttpResponse response = exchange.getResponse();
        HttpServerResponse reactorResponse = getNativeResponse(response);
        HandshakeInfo handshakeInfo = handshakeInfoFactory.get();
        NettyDataBufferFactory bufferFactory = (NettyDataBufferFactory) response.bufferFactory();

        String originHeader = handshakeInfo.getHeaders()
                                           .getOrigin();// you will get ws://user:pass@localhost:8080

        return service.authenticate(originHeader)//returns Mono<Boolean>
                      .filter(Boolean::booleanValue)// filter the result
                      .doOnNext(a -> log.info("AUTHORIZED"))
                      .flatMap(a -> reactorResponse.sendWebsocket(subProtocol, this.maxFramePayloadLength, (in, out) -> {

                          ReactorNettyWebSocketSession session = //
                                  new ReactorNettyWebSocketSession(in, out, handshakeInfo, bufferFactory, this.maxFramePayloadLength);

                          return handler.handle(session);
                      }))
                      .switchIfEmpty(Mono.just("UNATHORIZED")
                                         .doOnNext(log::info)
                                         .then());

    }

    private static HttpServerResponse getNativeResponse(ServerHttpResponse response) {
        if (response instanceof AbstractServerHttpResponse) {
            return ((AbstractServerHttpResponse) response).getNativeResponse();
        } else if (response instanceof ServerHttpResponseDecorator) {
            return getNativeResponse(((ServerHttpResponseDecorator) response).getDelegate());
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Couldn't find native response in " + response.getClass()
                                                                                             .getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Moreover, if you do not have crucial logical dependencies onto Spring Security in the project such as complex ACL logic, then I advise you to get rid of it and even do not use it at all.

The reason for that is that I see Spring Security as a violator of the reactive approach due to its, I would say, MVC legacy mindset. It entangles your application with tons of extra configurations and "not-on-the-surface" tunings and forces engineers to maintain those configurations, making them more and more complex. In most cases, things could be implemented very smoothly without touching Spring Security at all. Just create a component and use it in a proper way.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation and code example.

Comment: @Dachstein glad it's useful!

Comment: Why couldn't we just protect an HTTP endpoint? Maybe I am wrong, but as I understand, it must be accessed just before upgrade, so it's protection should be enougth. If authentication at this point is successful, the following interaction will be within a session...