# WebFlux Security Context issue (Authentication is missing user details) #5225

Tags: spring-security

**High level Summary**

When using the WebFlux security configuration, the user details scope populated inside the Authentication object during the "ReactiveUserDetailsService" call is missing in the AuthorizationManager.

**Actual Behavior**

The Authentication object inside our custom "ReactiveAuthorizationManager" does not have the user details that is populated in our custom "ReactiveUserDetailsService".

**Expected Behavior**

The Authentication object inside "ReactiveAuthorizationManager" should have the user details populated up the chain in the "ReactiveUserDetailsService"

**Step By Step flow**

Below is our flow and Detail Summary.

1. AuthenticationWebFilter (we create our own instance of AuthenticationWebFilter and register respective managers, handlers, entry points etc..).
2. CustomReactiveAuthenticationManager (our own) is registered with the AuthenticationWebFilter
3. CustomReactiveUserDetailsService (our own) is registered with the ReactiveAuthenticationManager
4. Once the ReactiveUserDetailsService calls remote server and authenticates the request successfully, a Scope (User Details) is populated inside the Authentication.
5. The rest is all security framework flow: The Success handler is called.
6. Then the "SecurityContextServerWebExchangeWebFilter" is called.
7. At last the AuthorizationWebFilter is executed and the registered "AuthorizationManager" is invoked.
8. CustomAuthorizationManager (our own) is registered in the "authorizeExchange.pathMatchers.access"
9. We find that the UserDetails is missing inside the Authentication object when it reaches the custom AuthorizationManager.

**Sample**

I have created the below git repository for reference. Call the GET /v1/context API which invokes the "RbsAuthorizationManager" and note that the Authorization there is missing the "userDetails".

https://github.com/psathesh/auth-client-java-reactive

Opened up issue with
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/5225

Related references:
[Spring Webflux Websocket Security - Basic Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49545305/spring-webflux-websocket-security-basic-authentication)

Comment: Looking at the sample you provided, you have a custom `RbsAuthenticationManager` which creates a `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` with the principal "USER", credentials "N/A" etc. This is the `Authentication` object that is passed into your custom `RbsAuthorizationManager`. You are seeing different user details because they are created in the `RbsAuthenticationManager`.